# Katalon with external jar as dependency and not as a project resource?

Tags: jar, katalon-studio

When using our Git based [**Katalon** Studio](https://www.katalon.com/) project, we need to use an external jar.

According to the Katalon docs, [as can be seen here](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/import-java-library/), we need to paste the jar in our `Drivers` folder.

But the meaning of that is that we are pushing the jar into git, a pattern we don't really like (e.g. when new versions of the jar will be available, we can't simply use "latest")

From our Java projects we are customs to use dependencies in our projects/POM file, so the project's Git is not holding the dependencies jars.

Is there something similar in Katalon?

Answer (score 0):

Imagination is key here. I simply used [ant](https://ant.apache.org/) because why not . . .

Here is a dead simple build.xml, simply put at it at top level of your project.

```
<project name=app-tests" default="dist" basedir=".">
   <description>
      gets the dependencies
   </description>
   <!-- set global properties for this build -->
   <property name="dist" location="Drivers"/>

   <target name="install">

       <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>

       <!-- Joda Time -->
       <get src="http://central.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.1/joda-time-2.10.1.jar"
       dest="${dist}"
       verbose="true"
       usetimestamp="true"/>

       <!-- ibatis common -->
       <get src="https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/apache/ibatis- 
       common/2.2.0/ibatis-common-2.2.0.jar"
       dest="${dist}"
       verbose="true"
       usetimestamp="true"/>

       <!-- json simple -->
       <get src="https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/json-simple/json-simple-1.1.1.jar"
       dest="${dist}"
       verbose="true"
       usetimestamp="true"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Then run:

```
ant install
```

One could also do this with some bash action with curl or wget get kinda like so:

```
wget -P ./Drivers/ http://central.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.1/joda-time-2.10.1.jar
```

Then pop a few of those into a build.sh and you're good to go.

Remember to restart Katalon for the the new items in the Drivers folder to take effect. 
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is: create a maven project under the same root-directory with katalon project, and add 'maven-dependency-plugin' plugin in the POM file，when run 'mvn clean packge', copy the target jar to the Drivers directory, and keep the jar in Drivers dir **do not** commit to git server.